# PHP SOAP error - "XML String empty"

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to make a SOAP call (TravelGuard API) with PHP SOAP client, something like this.

```
$arr = array('asdasdasd'=>array(
                'asdasd'=>array(
                        'asdasd'=>array(
                                'asdsad'=>'008573',
                                'asdasd'=>'114846',
                                'asdasd'=>'Quote',
                                'asasdasd'=>'1',
                                'asdasdas'=>'4000.00',
                        ),
                        'asdasd'=>array(
                                'asdas'=>array(
                                        'asdasd'=>'4000.00'
                                ),
                        ),
                        'asdasd'=>array(
                                'asdasd'=>'21-09-2012',
                                'asdasd'=>'10-10-2012',
                                'asdasd'=>'22-08-2012',
                        )
                )
        )
        );



        $options = array(
               'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 
               'exceptions'=>true, 
               'trace'=>1,'encoding'=>'utf-8'
               );
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->PDUrl, $options);

        //$xmlVar = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);

        $res = $this->client->getQuote(array('xmlString'=>$arr));
        var_dump($res);exit;
```

This returns an error with code `'101010'` and description as `'XML String empty'`

The support team has advised me to wrap the XML part in CDATA string. How can i do this?

Comment: did you try wrapping all your xml fields in CDATA?
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala, Yup, doesn't work. But i got a success with CURL calls where i can wrap entire xmlString in CDATA.